# How do I start KairosDB in DEBUG mode

Tags: cassandra, kairosdb

I want to get more information from KairosDB queries and want to start it in DEBUG mode. I can't find a log4j file or any log level setting in conf/kairosdb.properties. Where can I set the log level to DEBUG in Kairos ?

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out.

1. Grab a sample logback.xml like https://github.com/proofpoint/kairosdb/blob/master/src/main/resources/logback.xml. In the fine O
2. Put it in your Kairos directory say inside /opt/kairos/lib
3. In the bin/kairosdb.sh change JAVA_OPTS to 
   JAVA_OPTS=-Dlogback.configurationFile=lib/logback.xml
4. Restart KairosDB.